Does .editorconfig have any property that organize includes in c++?
I would like to organize my include statements in order and in blocks, similar to the .clangd configuration. I need to know if the .clangd or eclipse configuration are the only options to organize my includes or if I can follow the project pattern, which uses the .editorconfig file.
Also, is it possible to work with both at the same time in VS Code or Visual Studio?
Although I tried to search for some configuration I could use in .editorconfig, I just find configurations in clang-format or eclipse.
Update: I found this question that explains how to configure two formatters in vs code, but it does not support c++, is there a way to make samething similar?
I still wonder if it is possible with only .editorconfig as well.
